# Htaccess Redirect Loop Issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For particular reasons, I'm hosting a subsite within a parent site, and would like to use a domain alias for the subsite. For clarity, let's call the two domains parent.org and child.org.

The subsite is located at: parent.org/child

Since child.org is a domain alias, it's also located at: child.org/child

I'd like to build redirects that route any requests to either child.org or parent.org/child to child.org/child

Scouring the forums, I've attempted a number of things, though this one seemed the closest to what I'm going for:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?child\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/child/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://child.org/child/$1 [R=302,L,NS]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parent\.org/child$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://child.org/child/$1 [R=302,L,NS]
```

This doesn't quite work as hoped, resulting in child.org/child/child/child/etc.

What am I missing here?

**Addendum:**
To help clarify my goal here, for either domain, if "/child" isn't the first segment of the URL, I'd like to use parent.org. If "/child" isn't the first segment of the URL, I'd like to use child.org. So:

```
Parent setup:
parent.org/foo ->  parent.org/foo
parent.org/child/foo -> child.org/child/foo

Child setup:
child.org -> child.org/child
child.org/foo -> parent.org/foo
child.org/child/foo -> child.org/child/foo
```

Comment: so the  request , child.org/whatever , if whatever not child it should be redirected to parent.org/whatever right?

Comment: That's right. Kind of ridiculous, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parent\.org/child$ [NC]` is wrong because   `%{HTTP_HOST}` is representing either `parent.org` or `child.org` and could not match `uri` after them.

And i think you have no issue with `child.org` because it is already done before by `domain alias` which means that the request to `child.org` will show up every thing in `child` directory unless you do another configuration .

So , your code should looks like this , to redirect only when parent domain is involved :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?parent\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/child/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^child/(.*)$ http://child.org/$1 [R=302,L]
```

So , this part `parent.org/child/` is already configured as `child.org` so any request contains `parent.org/child/whatever` will be `child.org/whatever`

**Update :** you siad **Since child.org is a domain alias, it's also located at: child.org/child** if that so ,the code should look like this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?parent\.org$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/child/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://child.org/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?child\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/child/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://parent.org/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?child\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/child/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://child.org/child/$1 [R=302,L]
```

So , any request to `parent.org/child/whatever` will be redirected to `child.org/child/whatever`

Then any request to `child.org/whatever` and wherever is everything except `child` will be redirected to `parent.org/whatever`

Finally , any request to `child.org` will be redirected to `child.org/child/`

Comment: Thanks for your response! This has given me some clarity, but I'm this doesn't quite solve the issue. Perhaps I can frame it clearer -- I'll add to the original post.

Comment: Wow, we're making progress! The following aspects work:
parent.org/foo ->  parent.org/foo
child.org/foo -> parent.org/foo

These ones seem to work at first, returning the expected, correct URL in the browser:
parent.org/child/foo -> child.org/child/foo
child.org -> child.org/child
child.org/child/foo -> child.org/child/foo

But the the page itself throws an "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS". Is something still looping when it hits child.org/child?

I can confirm there's no other interfering redirects in the htaccess file.

Comment: @Marcus i added RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?parent\.org$ [NC] at the beginning , so clear browser cache then test it again

Comment: Thanks for the update! That's gotten me pretty far -- I've commented out the 2nd block, which stops any "too many redirects" errors, and meets all conditions except one: child.org/foo -> parent.org/foo. I've tried rearranging and modifying that 2nd block, but I can't get it to play with the other two.